# closed strong vs. closed in weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Studying a chapter about weak topologies and weak convergence I though the following which I have no idea how to prove or disprove it. So here it is:

> **Question:** Does there exist  Banach space $X$ and a closed subset $F
>  \subset X$ such that $F$ is not closed with respect to weak
>   convergence?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,  if $X$ is infinite dimensional. For example
$$
\operatorname{cl}_{\sigma(X,X^*)}(S_X)=B_X
$$
See exercisre 3.46 in [Banach space theory. The basis for linear and non-linear analysis. M. Fabian, P. Habala, P. Hajek, V. Montesinos, V. Zizler.](http://books.google.ru/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

If $X$ is finite dimensional, then weak and strong toplogy coincide. See proposition 3.13 in the same book. Thus closedness in both topologies is the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! THank you also for the reference of the book!

Comment: You are wellcome!

Comment: @passenger You can find a proof of the first fact [here at MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/prove-the-weak-closure-of-the-unit-sphere-is-the-unit-ball).

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes I found it there! Thank you for your comment-reply!