# Weak closure of the boundary of the unit ball of $l^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to prove that zero is in the weak closure of set $\{ x\in l^1 \,:\, \lVert x\rVert =1\}$ . And I need example too.
Is there any countable subset of this set which has $0$ in weak closure?

Comment: The key observation (which follows from the definition of weak neighbourhood) is that all weakly-open subsets in and infinitely dimensional normed space contain a straight line.

Comment: For the second part: let $A=\{x\in l^1\,:\, \lVert x\rVert=1\}$. There is a countable subset $S\subseteq A$ whose strong closure is $A$. The weak closure of $S$ in $l^1$ contains the strong closure of $S$ in $l^1$...

Comment: Sassatelli has given some pretty strong hints regarding the right answers. It might be a good thing to realize that the following true fact does _not_ imply that there's no countable set with $0$ in the weak closure: There is no _sequence_ in $A$ that tends to $0$ weakly. (In fact, curiously, weak convergence of a _sequence_ in $l^1$ implies convergence in norm!)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/prove-the-weak-closure-of-the-unit-sphere-is-the-unit-ball