# How to show that $\partial B(0,1)$ is not weakly closed set?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let X be an infinite dimensional  normed $\mathbb K$-linear space .Prove that $\partial B(0,1)=\{x\in X: ||x||= 1\}$ is not weakly closed in $X$.

We know that a **convex** subset of $X$ is weakly closed iff it is closed w.r.t. the normed topology. But here $\partial B(0,1)$ is not convex in X.

(definition of weak topology): Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$ -linear space . The weak topology of $X$ is the smallest topology $J_{\omega}$(which is a subset of the normed topology of X) such that $f:(X,J_{\omega})\to\mathbb K$ is continuous for all $f \in X^*.$

Please someone give some hints.

Thank you.

Comment: Should you maybe replace $\le$ by $=$?

Comment: The claim is false for finite-dimensional $X$.

Comment: Take a look at this post
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/prove-the-weak-closure-of-the-unit-sphere-is-the-unit-ball)

Comment: @amsmath  I apologize ..I have edited now.

Comment: If you have any questions about the link that Gio gave you, go ahead and ask here.