# Weak star closure of the unit sphere in the dual space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space with its dual $X^*$. Let $\mathbb{S}^*$ be the unit sphere of $X^*$. We have known that if $X$ (or $X^*$) is reflexive then the weak-star and weak topology of $X^*$ coincide and thus the weak-star closure (or weak closure) of $\mathbb{S}^*$ is the unit ball. I have the following questions:

1. If $X$ is reflexive, what is the weak-star sequential closure of $\mathbb{S}^*$?
2. If $X$ is non-reflexive, what are the weak-star and weak-star sequential closure of $\mathbb{S}^*$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/prove-the-weak-closure-of-the-unit-sphere-is-the-unit-ball)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! But I am considering the weak-star closure of the dual unit ball, not the weak closure, in the case $X$ is non-reflexive.

Comment: The weak star closure is larger than weak closure, as there are less open sets.

Comment: Thank you! Please review my edited questions.

Comment: Looks fine. I do not know much about sequential closure, except that it is smaller than the usual closure. If $X$ is separable then (I have impression) the weak star topology on $B^*$ is metrizable. So sequential weak star closure and weak star closure coincide for bounded sets.